# click detection using python (for maya 3D)

Tags: python, click, detection, maya, autodesk

I'm interesting about making a python tool for maya, and I need to detect a click input from user, basicaly to create a cube each time the user click with his left mouse button. But the problem is that I don't know how to do it.. I have good knowleges about python but not with that...

If someone could help me, it will be wonderful !
Thank in advance !

Comment: Try clicking first.  That should generate a cube for you

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on draggerContext and if you search enough there are result every where about that :) .. But here is minimal working example..

```
def createCubesForFun():
    x, y, z = tuple(cmds.draggerContext( 'cubeFunCtx', query=1, dragPoint=1))
    newBox = cmds.polyCube()
    cmds.setAttr("%s.t" % newBox[0], x, y, z)

cmds.draggerContext('cubeFunCtx', dragCommand='createCubesForFun()', space='world')    
cmds.setToolTo('cubeFunCtx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with PyQt. Detecting some focus widget. And then on click, find whatever is selected

```
import sip
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


def getMayaWindow():
    """Get the maya main window as a QMainWindow instance"""
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)


def getFocusWidget():
    """Get the currently focused widget"""
    return QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()


def getWidgetAtMouse():
    """Get the widget under the mouse"""
    currentPos = QtGui.QCursor().pos()
    widget = QtGui.qApp.widgetAt(currentPos)
    return widget

# This is the syntax to find the right click button
# QtGui.qApp.mouseButtons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton
```